# Sails server fails to start. Probably due to association in models

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, postman

I am using Sails for a project. I used Chrome POSTMAN to create a model instance. After that, I can not start sails server. The error message is attached below.

I realized that this is due to association I have in the model. How can I use POSTMAN to correctly create User instance?

`api/model/User.js`:

```
module.exports = {

connection: 'localDiskDb',

attributes: {

    firstName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        minLength: 1,
        string: true,
        alphadashed: true
    },

    lastName: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        minLength: 2,
        string: true,
        alphadashed: true
    },

    cars: {
        collection: 'car',
        via: 'owner'
    }    
}
```

Error message when lifting sails:

```
 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/
 waterline/core/typecast.js:56

Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {

                   ^
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at Cast.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/core/typecast.js:56:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/database.js:209:46
    at Array.map (native)
    at Database.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/database.js:208:32)
    at Array.async.auto.checkData [as 0] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-disk/lib/database.js:59:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:459:38
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at Object.async.auto (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:430:9)
```

Comment: You can at least get Sails to lift again by deleting (or moving) you database file (probably `.tmp/localDisk.db`).  Then check any models that have associations to make sure the references to other models are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly we need to improve the error message in this case.

Your `via` property is incorrect for the `cars` association. It should reference the reverse association in the `Car` model (if you want to be able to populate a car's users in a query) or just removed entirely. So, in `api/models/Car.js` you could have:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    users: {

      collection: "User",
      via: "cars"

    },

    ...other attrs...

  }
}
```

and then set the `via` in `User.js` to `users`.  Also try uppercasing `Car` in the `collection` property; I've seen that mysteriously be a problem from time to time.

Comment: Fixed all those issues. The car model has attribute `user: { model: 'User' }`. I first start sails server, then post to localhost:1337/user/create?firstName=joe&lastName=Small

Comment: Fixed all those issues. The car model has attribute `user: { model: 'User' }`. I first start sails server with no prior data, then POST to localhost:1337/user/create?firstName=joe&lastName=Small Server runs normal. I use GET localhost:1337/user. The result shows the id of user joe Small is 2(?). After that, I use Ctrl + C to stop the server and tries to lift again. The error message is the same.

Comment: Did you clear your database first? Might be some bad data in there.

Comment: I used `rm .tmp/localDisk.db` before everything.